# Warning: file_put_contents(./aa.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied - in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Im getting this warning when trying to append data to a text file - I've looked around a lot and tried many things, changing permissions (eg. chmod'd to 777 and given www permissions) etc., but nothing I've tried seems to work. I'm using XAMPP 7.1.7, on MacOS.

Wondering if I'm just doing something obviously wrong or haven't setup a part of xampp.

```
$url = "text";
$filename = "./data.txt" ;
file_put_contents($filename, $url, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I've found your problem - you don't need to use terminal actually, problem is you need to give read/write access to everyone - I had a similar problem like that and it can be fixed like so.

If you go to you your directory containing your htdocs, xamppfiles etc. (this is normally by default a folder called 'XAMPP' in Applications), right click on the folder and select 'Get Info'. Another window will pop up and here at the bottom will be a sharing and permissions drop down - from there you can see a table, and next to 'Everyone' select 'Read and Write' in the Privilege dropdown.
You can then go ahead an below that select "Apply to all subfolders".

This should fix it!

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly - supprissed i didn't come across it on other posts i've searched at.

Answer (score 0):

that mean  your `php.exe` does not have Permission to write file, try Disable `User Account Control (UAC)` or run php in `CMD` to debug

Comment: Im on MacOS, and running the php in terminal just gives me a parse error

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change your Xampp Apache settings.

File location : Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf

Set section with your user and group to allow PHP to write :

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User deamon
Group deamon
</IfModule>
```

change

```
User deamon
```

to

```
User [your user name]
```

and

```
Group deamon
```

to

```
Group #-1
```